# Oracle SQL function or buckets for data filtering

Tags: sql, oracle, bucket, rownum

```
SELECT 
     transaction
    ,date
    ,mail
    ,status
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY mail ORDER BY date) AS rownum
FROM table1
```

[image]

Having the above table and script I want to be able to filter the transactions on the basis of having first 3 rowids with status 'failed' to show rowid 4 if 'failed', having transactions with rowid 4,5,6 failed - show 7 if also failed etc. I was thinking about adding it to a pandas dataframe where to run a simple lambda function , but would really like to find a solution in SQL only.

Comment: not sure what you need here. please explain it better or show the expected output.

Comment: I would need only the transactions of lapplin4@diigo.com remaining. Only the users who have made 4 consecutive 'failed' transactions may remain in the end result.

Comment: but `lapplin4@diigo.com` has only 3 consecutive FAILED transactions. the 4th is SUCCESSFUL in the example shown..also clarify if it the consecutive FAILED should be =4 or >=4.

Comment: Yep, my bad, should be FAILED. >=4 would be the condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `lead()` and `lag()` to explicitly check:

```
select t.*
from (select t1.*,
             lag(status, 3) over (partition by mail order by date) as status_3,
             lag(status, 3) over (partition by mail order by date) as status_2,
             lag(status, 3) over (partition by mail order by date) as status_1,
             lead(status, 1) over (partition by mail order by date) as status_3n,
             lead(status, 2) over (partition by mail order by date) as status_2n,
             lead(status, 3) over (partition by mail order by date) as status_3n
      from t
     ) t
where status = 'FAILED' and
      ( (status_3 = 'FAILED' and status_2 = 'FAILED' and status_1 = 'FAILED') or
        (status_2 = 'FAILED' and status_1 = 'FAILED' and status_1n = 'FAILED') or
        (status_1 = 'FAILED' and status_1n = 'FAILED' and status_2n = 'FAILED') or
        (status_1n = 'FAILED' and status_2n = 'FAILED and status_3n = 'FAILED')
      )
```

This is a bit brute force, but I think the logic is quite clear.

You could simplify the logic to:

```
where regexp_like(status_3 || status_2 || status_1 || status || status_1n || status_2n || status3n,
                  'FAILED{4}'
                 )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select * from (
SELECT 
     transaction
    ,date
    ,mail
    ,status
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY mail ORDER BY date) AS rownum
FROM table1
WHERE status = 'FAILED' )
where mod(rownum, 3) = 1;
```

Richard

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use window functions. Use `lag` to get the previous status value (based on specified ordering) and compare it with the current row's value and assign groups with a running sum. Then count the values in each group and finally filter for that condition.

```
SELECT t.*
FROM
  ( SELECT t.*,
           count(*) over(PARTITION BY mail, grp) AS grp_count
   FROM
     ( SELECT t.*,
              sum(CASE
                      WHEN (prev_status IS NULL AND status='FAILED') OR 
                           (prev_status='FAILED' AND status='FAILED') THEN 0
                      ELSE 1
                  END) over(PARTITION BY mail ORDER BY "date","transaction") AS grp
      FROM
        ( SELECT t.*,
                 lag(status) over(PARTITION BY mail ORDER BY "date","transaction") AS prev_status
         FROM tbl t 
        ) t 
     ) t 
 ) t
WHERE grp_count>=4
```

If you are using versions starting with Oracle 12c, there is an option to use `MATCH_RECOGNIZE` which would simplify this.

```
select *
from tbl
MATCH_RECOGNIZE (
         PARTITION BY mail
         ORDER BY "date" ,"transaction"
         ALL ROWS PER MATCH
         AFTER MATCH SKIP TO LAST FAIL
         PATTERN(fail{4,})
         DEFINE 
         fail AS (status='FAILED')
       ) MR
ORDER BY "date","transaction"
```